# Multiple directives in one ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have got the following code. This obviously doesn't work because I'm mixing resource with la. How can I mix these correctly?

```
   <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="la in lang">
                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">{{la}}</label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <textarea ui-tinymce ng-model="resource.la"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: can you please include also the rest of the code? it's too few as is

Comment: also, if you please tell us what is the structure of "resource" object. Does it contains a la variable or it contains a variable key-value pair?

Comment: what is the goal of this ? Being able to edit a description for each language ?

Comment: @Walfrat La contains a language string. For example fr for france de for german etc. Resource is the object in the data model. This is what is being pushed to angular later on.

Comment: pls atleast copy full code. Cannot understand what is resource object and how is it related to language or la ?

Comment: so resource is an array of language ? if so you can use $index provided by ng-repeat : <textarea ui-tinymce ng-model="resource[$index]"></textarea>. If resource is a object you can do : <textarea ui-tinymce ng-model="resource[la]"></textarea>. Is that you're looking for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="la in lang">
    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">{{la}}</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
         <textarea ui-tinymce ng-model="resource[la]"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this way you are not referencing the "la" property but you are calling the property that has the same name as the value of the string `la`.